# Importing WAV CDs into iTunes without conversion

Tags: itunes, wav, lossless

I would like to import some audio CDs into iTunes, keeping their Audio CD (WAV) format because they had been previously burned from MP3s, so they don't lose too much quality.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open iTunes Preferences, and under *General*, go to *Import Settings*.

Select *WAV Encoder*.

[image]