# Can I Import WM Player/wav album info into iTunes on Win7 PC?

Tags: hard-drive, itunes, music, windows-media-player, wav

I have a hard drive that contains about 500 cds that I ripped using Windows Media Player 64 (v11? - current version) on a Win7 64 PC in `wav` format. I also used WMP to retrieve the album info from the internet when I burned the cds. In WMP everything shows up fine - albums, artists, artwork, etc.

I wanted to import these wav files into iTunes on my Win7 64 PC, and load some of them onto an iPod. I followed the instructions given in the answer to this question: [Importing WAV CDs into iTunes without conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/351146/importing-wav-cds-into-itunes-without-conversion)  and that worked. I added all the folders that contain the `wav` files into iTunes and they show up and I can play them  and load them onto the iPod the same way.

**BUT** - all I get in iTunes is **a list of songs**, as encoded in the `wav` files themselves. I can see no album or artist info or artwork, etc in iTunes, although on the hard drive I can see the album art jpg's and also album info there, in a file called `desktop.ini`, apparently in a Windows format that is useless to iTunes. Is there a way I can import into iTunes that album info, or would I have to rip everything again using iTunes?

Note: There are several CD's that I ripped using `wma` format instead of `wav`, and ITunes prompted me if I wanted to convert them, I clicked OK, and those few CD's showed up in iTunes with all the album info (not sure about artwork though...). Might it be possible to convert the wav files to wma files and then import them into iTunes with all the info? That would be a lot easier than burning everything again.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes usually gets the album info from the tags embedded in the audio files themselves (also called metadata), but this doesn't apply to the WAV format, where iTunes doesn't support tags.

As suggested [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3565668), you can try using Max to convert the WAV files to a different format for which iTunes does read the tags.